# Uncaught Error: Class 'Sendgrid' not found in

Tags: php, composer-php, sendgrid

I'm getting an error when trying to use the Sendgrid API. The error comes up as:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Sendgrid' not found in signin.php:xxx Stack trace: #0 index.php(yy): require() #1 {main} thrown in signin.php on line xxx.
```

I installed Sendgrid using composer. I then register the autoloader like:

**index.php**

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Then follow the guide like on the link below.

**signin.php**

```
use SendGrid\Mail\From;
use SendGrid\Mail\To;
use SendGrid\Mail\Mail;

$from = new From("test@example.com", "Example User");
$to = [
    new To(
        "test+test1@example.com",
        "Example User",
        [
            'subject' => 'Subject'
        ]
    )
];
$email = new Mail(
    $from,
    $tos
);

$email->setTemplateId("REDACTED");
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));
```

The autoload.php file works with other composer classes.

Steps I've tried so far:

1. Uninstall sendgrid and re-install.
2. Called the sendgrid-php.php manually to verify sending emails work.

**Reference**

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/main/USE_CASES.md#send-an-email-to-a-single-recipient

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "sendgrid/sendgrid": "^8.0",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up putting the code inside of a function and it worked without issue. I required mailer.php right after autoload.php.

In case someone runs into this issue, here is what I did. Obviously, you'll want to customize it to your needs.

**mailer.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use SendGrid\Mail\From;
use SendGrid\Mail\To;
use SendGrid\Mail\Mail;

function mailer() {
    $from = new From("test@example.com", "Example User");
    $to = new To(
        "test+test1@example.com",
        "Example User",
        [
            'subject' => 'Subject'
        ]
    );
    $email = new Mail($from, $to);

    $email->setTemplateId("REDACTED");
    $sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));
}
```

I'm not sure why my original code did not work, but this solution works so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Writing code into the global scope defeats the autoloader: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: Can you suggest how to fix this?

Comment: @holdmydev The OP did that already